# Port not opening on Ubuntu Server for Pocketmine

Tags: ubuntu, port, minecraft, pocketmine

I am trying to run a `PHP` server, for `Minecraft PE`.  The server is called `Pocketmine`.  The port will not open for me for this particular server.  I am trying to run the server on port `19132`, but it is always closed.  Just to make sure the port is open in my router, I run a Rails server on that port and everything works fine.  When I switch back over to the Pocketmine server, it fires up fine and says that it is listening on `19132`, but my port remains closed.  Here is the console output.

[image]

Comment: What environment are we in here? is this windows or *nix?

Comment: *nix.  I am running Ubuntu Server.

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that Pocketmine opens a UDP port, not a TCP port. Given this fact, your test with Ruby on Rails doesn't really tell us anything, as it opens a TCP port.

Most likely thing is that there is a firewall in the way. Open the correct UDP port and redirect it to your server. Check your server for local firewall settings.

From the output of Pocketmine I see no reason for it not to work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the stable installation, which often doesn't accept requests from the most recent version of Minecraft PE. Install the alpha version.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a firewall installed. To check use `ufw status | grep "Status:*"`

If you get `Status: active` as a result you must add the `19132` port to the firewall in order for your pocketmine server to run.

Use `ufw allow 19132` or `ufw allow <your pocketmine server's port>` to add the port to the firewall.

Then just reload the firewall with `ufw reload`.